# Linear independence of set in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

I have a vector space W, and a subspace $S \subseteq W$.
If there is a set of linearly independent vectors such that $\{w1, ..., w_n\} \subset S$,
is $\{w1, ..., w_n\}$ also linearly independent in V?

Comment: Definitions are your friends!  I suspect you have a typo in the last line, referring to $V$ which was not previously mentioned.  In its present form the Question doesn't show research effort, so failing all else you could describe what motivates your problem or where you encountered it.  This would help convince Readers that you'd given the proposition some thought before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Reason:  Recall the condition for linear independence is $$ c_1v_1 + \ldots + c_nv_n = \bf{0} \iff c_1 = \ldots = c_n= 0. $$

Since the scalar field of $V$ and $W$ are the same, picking any coefficients $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ other than $0$ will sum to a nonzero vector, regardless of whether we consider the vectors, $v_i$, as elements of $W$ or $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true, and follows immediately from the definition of linear (in)dependence. Your set of vectors do not care about any other vectors lying in a larger space. You've probably proven that e.g. $A =\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ is a set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Of course, $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^5$, and so on. It would be strange if for some of these superspaces $A$ would be dependent and in other superspaces independent.

Comment: "*Of course, $\Bbb R^3$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ and $\Bbb R^5$, and so on*"  Not exactly... $\Bbb R^3$ is not strictly considered to even be a *subset* of $\Bbb R^4$.  After all, the elements in $\Bbb R^3$ are triples while elements in $\Bbb R^4$ are quadruples.  They aren't of the same form.  We do have that $\Bbb R^4$ has a subspace which is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$, but it has many such subspaces and not just the one.